# In bash shell, how do I load the value of a property in a properties (env) file into a var in my bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I have

```
SA_PASSWORD=Password1!
```

in a file, tests/.makefile_test_env.  I would like to get the value "Password1!" into a variable on my bash shell.  I tried this

```
$ MY_VAR=$(grep SA_PASSWORD tests/.makefile_test_env | xargs)
```

Unfortunately, this returns

```
$ echo $MY_VAR
SA_PASSWORD=Password1!
```

How do I filter out the "SA_PASSWORD=" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this doing the `cut` command; keep in mind, though, it may not be a good idea to keep passwords inside of scripts.

```
[ekaj@headdesk ~]$ cat vars
SA_PASSWORD=Password1!
[ekaj@headdesk ~]$ cat setvar.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "MY_VAR is currently set to: $MY_VAR"
MY_VAR=$(grep SA_PASSWORD ./vars | cut -d'=' -f 2-)
echo "MY_VAR is currently set to: $MY_VAR"
[ekaj@headdesk ~]$
[ekaj@headdesk ~]$ ./setvar.sh
MY_VAR is currently set to:
MY_VAR is currently set to: Password1!
[ekaj@headdesk ~]$
```

The `-f 2-` prints all fields after the first `=`, which might be handy if your password happens to have an equals sign in it.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it, try using extended regex and the look behind pattern and only (also you don't need the pipe to `xargs`):

```
MY_VAR=$(grep -Po '(?<=SA_PASSWORD=).*' tests/.makefile_test_env)
```

This says:

1. Make a shell variable called 'MY_VAR' and set it to whatever comes out of $() which is...
2. grep using `-P` perl regex and `-o` only return the match for this pattern '...' which is
3. `(?<=SA_PASSWORD=).*` this means match any character any number of times `.*`, but only if the characters just before `(?<=)` the first `.` are 'SA_PASSWORD=' oh and don't include them as part of the match.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the variable doesn't matter you could `source` it.

```bsh
source tests/.makefile_test_env
echo $SA_PASSWORD # Prints Password1!
```

**WARNING**: Performing source on an untrusted file is dangerous. You're executing a shell script, and that script can perform anything you could do yourself.